# How to construct predefined random number generator and seed sequence in constructor?

Tags: c++, random, c++17

### Background

I'm building a discrete selector, e.g. given a sequence, it picks randomly one element with probability according to given weights. You can think of it as a pair of `PredefinedRandomGenerator` and `std::discrete_distribution`. I'd like the selector to be portable, and provide sane entropy. It will **not** be used in cryptographic context, I just want better randomness (sorry if I messed up terminology here).

### Problem

`std:random_device` on MinGW on Windows always yields the same number. As a workaround, I use

```
//assume using namespace std::chrono
std::seed_seq seq{std::random_device{}(), 
                  duration_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(),
                  42};
```

The problem is that the constructor of `PredefinedRandomGenerator` expects lvalue-reference, so I cannot initialize it in member initializer list as follows:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
discrete_selector(InputIterator weights_first,
                  InputIterator weights_last):
        generator(std::seed_seq{/*...*/}),
        distribution(weights_first, weights_last)
{}
```

So now there is at least one source of more or less random number.

### What I tried

```
//somewhere in namespace details
std::seed_seq& get_new_sequence()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<std::seed_seq> sequence;
    sequence = std::make_unique<std::seed_seq>(std::random_device{}(), 
                                            duration_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(),
                                            42);
    return *sequence;
}
```

The above should work, but I believe there should be a better way of doing that.

---

### Side question

Why does constructor take the `std::seed_seq` by lvalue reference? It could at least use rvalue-reference.

Comment: I didn't post it on [CodeReview.se] first because I thought this might be useful here. If it isn't, feel free to VTC, I'll delete it after having dinner.

Comment: Not terribly pretty, but you could just seed the generator in the constructor body.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, I didn’t want to impose more restrictions on Generator, as in real code it gets SFINAEd away if there is no constructor taking seed_seq. There is variadic template one, which is a plan B.

Comment: Alternatively, you could get the already seeded generator from the class' users as a constructor argument, or as an argument to whatever function actually does the selecting. The latter matches the interface of the standard distributions and both have the advantage that the user can pick their own generator. (The disadvantage of *that* being of course that users tend to choose poorly, like `std::default_random_engine`.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen yeah I tend to agree. I prefer to use either random_device or chrono::high_resolution_clock as a typical seed to the mersenne_twister `mt19937` or `mt19937_64` engine. Some times I'll use seed_seq if I want some deterministic feature, but yeah;  default_random_engine is only useful if someone is rolling a 3-20 sided dice. I'm currently working on an elaborate set of classes within a library that will incorporate almost all of the random engines, seeding mechanisms and distributions through static methods of a class, with a universal function template to quickly choose any combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I typically do is use a lambda.

```
generator([]() -> auto& {
    static std::seed_seq seq(std::random_device()(), 
              duration_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count(),
              42);
    return seq;
}())
```

If you want to, you can always put that lambda in another private function like you did, which is also fine for all intents and purposes.

---

Or, like the [tree with eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen) said, you can initialize the seed in the constructor. :)

Comment: seed_seq has deleted operator= :)

Comment: @Incomputable But I'm not using that operator, no?

Comment: @Incomputable Oh, I understand now! Wait a sec. Corrected, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to add a declaration?

You currently have this:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
discrete_selector(InputIterator weights_first,
                  InputIterator weights_last):
        generator(std::seed_seq{/*...*/}),
        distribution(weights_first, weights_last)
{}
```

Considering the fact that `std::seed_seq` is non copyable - non moveable 
Instead of rewriting your existing constructor you can overload it as such:

```
#include <isostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <random>

template<class IntType = int>
class discrete_selector {
private:
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::discrete_distribution<IntType> distribution;

public:
    template<class InputIt>
    discrete_selector( InputIt wf, InputIt wl ) :
        generator( std::seed_seq{} ),
        distribution( wf, wl ) 
    {}

    // Constructor that takes an initializer list; you can not initialize
    // std::seed_seq by constructor in initializer list then pass it to a 
    // random generator or engine. seed_seq is non copy non moveable and     
    // besides that; the engines will not be able to convert the parameter 
    // type even if you tried. We have to create an instance of seed_seq in 
    // the constructor's body and we can then pass to it the initializer 
    // list from the constructor's parameter list. After we construct the
    // seed_seq then we can use our engine's or generator's `seed` function
    // and pass to it whatever type of seed we are using. In this case seed_seq
    template<class InputIt, class Type>
    discrete_selector( InputIt wf, InputIt wl, std::initializer_list<Type> list ) :
        distribution( wf, wl ) 
    {
        std::seed_seq seq( list );
        generator.seed( seq );
    }

    std::mt19937 getGenerator() {
        return generator;
    }

    IntType getDistributionMin() {
        return distribution.min();
    }

    IntType getDistributionMax() {
        return distribution.max();
    }

    // Copy?
    std::discrete_distribution<IntType> getDistribution()  {
        return distribution;
    }

    // Ref?
    void getDistribution( std::discrete_distribution<IntType>&& dd )  {
        dd = distribution;
    }

    std::vector<double> getDistriubtionProbabilities() {
        return distribution.probabilities();
    }

    int generate() {
        return distribution( generator );
    }

    int generate( int& val ) {
        val = distribution( generator );
    }
};

// main program demo example    
int main() {
    std::initializer_list<unsigned> list{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    discrete_selector<> ds( 100, 10000, list );
    int val = ds.generate();

    std::vector<double> probs{ ds.getDistriubtionProbabilities() };
    for( auto p : probs ) {
        std::cout << p << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //std::discrete_distribution<> dd = ds.getDistribution();
    //std::mt19937 gen = ds.getGenerator();
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> m;
    for( int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n ) {
        ++m[ds.generate()]; // use class built in function
    }

    for( auto p : m ) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```